# Unable to Update Several Packages

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager, settings

In the past two weeks, I could not update my Ubuntu system 14.04 LTS. In particular, every time I turn on my computer, the following window pops up.

[image]

After I click "Install Now", it asks for my password. After I type my password, the following window pops up.

[image]

If I click OK, then nothing happens and next time the same thing repeat. If I click "Settings...", the following window pops up.

[image]

However, I am not sure what to do with it.

**Did anyone have similar experience before? How to fix it, please? Thank you!**

**Update:**

After typing `sudo apt-get update` as suggested in the comments, I got a long list and the following error message.

```
Fetched 3,393 kB in 40s (84.1 kB/s)                                            
W: GPG error: http://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/piotr-zagawa/ma2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/piotr-zagawa/ma2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/piotr-zagawa/ma2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And there is also the following errors:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [133 kB]      
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
```

Comment: You would probably get more information if you Ctrl-Alt-T opened a command line terminal, and typed `sudo apt-get update`, and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Either `sudo` command may ask for your password.

Comment: @waltinator I did that. What do I do next, please? BTW, there was a long list. Some started with `Ign`, some with `Hit`, and some with `Get`.

Comment: Read the messages that seem to indicate an error, and copy them into your question.

Comment: What do you want me to copy, please? The whole thing after `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: No that's fine. The `404` errors may hint at a connectivity problem.

Comment: @waltinator What do I do then?

Answer (score 0):

This commmand should fix your (untrusted-package) :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

Comment: After typing that, I got `gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...` What should I do? Also what was the problem in the first place, please?